# Good ways to format a file

Tags: c#, design-patterns, file-format

At my job, I need to format payments file to be able to communicate with banks. The problem is that all bank ask for a different format. Right now, we use the Template Method pattern [GOF] in a attempt to do this as generics as possible but in result of the same 3 classes repeat for every format.

a class inherit from asbtract absPaymentFile (with Inversion of Control)
a class inherit from Payment (contain info about the payment sometime have 1 or 2 attribute different of the others payments classes)
a class inherit from absMerchant (contain info about the merchant and some method to implement)

Is there a way to format a file, with "almost" the same information, in several ways better than what we do now  ?

this link should provide you a good base line of what i need to do : https://www.vancity.com/lang/fr/SharedContent/documents/CPA_Std005_Specs.doc

It's a .doc !

Thanks !

Comment: Maybe you can share the code? Or at least tell us what you don't like in your approach. Otherwise it is not clear what to advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having gone down the path of trying to make something which would only need minor tweaks to support multiple formats, I'd say don't.  DRY principles don't really apply here because each new format is really and truly independent of the others and may change.

Yes, it might mean copy/pasting fair amounts of code but honestly once one format is done then you don't have to worry about it until the receiving software updates their spec.  Also, if that format changes you usually don't want any of those changes to impact your other output code.

In short, this is one of those areas that should only be encapsulated to the point of having some type of plugin architecture.  Meaning, all of the classes should implement a basic interface that simply defines how your main app is going to transfer data to it.  After that the classes should be able to diverge significantly from each other AND updates in one should have no impact in others.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into using a format supported by a C# library such as XML or [JSON](http://json.codeplex.com/) so you don't have to reinvent the wheel when reading or writing the file. Both of the mentioned formats would allow you to have optional attributes. For example

```
<elements>
    <element name="name1" value1="somevalue" company1specific="something" />
    <element name="name1" value1="somevalue" specificToAnotherCompany="something" />
</element>
```

or

```
{
    "elements" : [
        { "name":"name1", "company1specific":"something" },
        { "name":"name1", "specificToAnotherCompany":"something" }
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe he is restricted in format, he needs advice on how to design 'formatting' code

Comment: Ahh I see. Sorry I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

If flat file formats are being used take a look at this library: http://www.filehelpers.com/. The library will allow you to represent a format using a class with class and member attributes.

Also, it is easy to get carried away with re-use at this level of granularity. If generating file formats is not the core of what you're working on, it is more important to pay attention to architecture at a higher level then re-usability in file generation. Moreover, it might be helpful to keep formatting routines isolated from each other, so that changes for one format do not affect the other. Incorporating unit tests will further improve maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

You need an internal "Master Format" and then a DocumentConverter that takes the MasterFormatFile and converts it to the desired output.

Make the MasterFormatFile expose a generic api, almost like a get key-value as a Dictionary but with some other support.

Extending to a new FileFormatter Will be easy and modular.